# IE issue with image size

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have an unordered list on the left side i use as tabs to change a picture on the right side. The problem i have is that in IE the image is a few pix wider than in all other browsers so it displays below where i need it to be displayed. example here at [www.widgiteer.com](http://www.widgiteer.com/index.php#growingbusinesses).

BTW the black part is the test image i am using that is the correct size just as a place holder for future images.

I am also having trouble making the left tabs change color on hover but i think that is a different question :/

Comment: The image is wider in IE? Are you sure? Something else must be affecting the image. Take all styles and JS off and then see if the image is wider.

Comment: i have tried just using inline style and the only js i have is to run the tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are setting all your margins to zero, since browsers add different padding and margins to their elements. So add a global selector to your css...

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0}
```

also make sure your images have not borders:

```
img {border: none;}
```

final solution: Your doctype was set incorrectly.

Comment: so the black space I see on the right, is that an img tag? or just an empty div?

Comment: Didn't think of that but i set borders to none but it didn't do the trick.    the black space on the right is a black image place holder.

Comment: Make sure your img tags are closed. <img src="" id="" />

Comment: and you did make sure that your css reads, img {border: none;} ?

Comment: all image tags are closed and i cant find a syntax error anywhere. and the border is set to none.

Comment: well I'm looking at your code and your image tags are opened. So you fixed this?

Comment: yes, idk what program you are using but my zend program before i upload the code and firebug tells me that the image tags are closed with a </img> on each image

Comment: Check your site in validator... you have several errors in your code that could be causing this...http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: none of them are connected to the image but i will try to fix them. idk how accurate that site is because this page has more than 5 errors, yahoo has 200 and GOOGLE.com has 38 errors

Comment: Well you have issues like closed tags that aren't opened. I'm pretty sure this is just an issue with margin somewhere. Just add a negative margin of -6px to you img and see what happens.

Comment: omg it was the freaking doctype. darn you IE and your strict doctype! your the best michael rader

Comment: awesome! I'm glad you found it!

Comment: make an answer dont just comment because i dont think i can give you points on a comment

Comment: just award my answer as the correct response and then give an up vote. You use the check mark on the left of my answer at the top.

Comment: I updated the answer and put your final solution. Please award me the  answer. thanks :)

Comment: o lol didnt realize you gave that first answer, thought you just commented